# which rendering methode for facebook app is better , using fbml or iframe

Tags: facebook

in past I have used fbml rendering but now there is to many 
update on facebook sdk
I Feel Old sometimes !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FBML will be deprecated soon so you should use iframe

Source: http://developers.facebook.com/roadmap

Also from [this august post](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/402):

> > We will begin supporting IFrames for Page tabs in the next few months. Developers building canvas applications should start using IFrames immediately. By the end of this year, we will no longer allow new FBML applications to be created, so all new canvas applications and Page tabs will have to be based on IFrames and our JavaScript SDK. We will, however, continue to support existing implementations of the older authentication mechanism as well as FBML on Page tabs and applications.